# Converting long double to CString

Tags: c++, mfc, c-strings, long-double

I am working on C++ MFC project build in unicode settings and I usually use function _`ttof` to convert `CString` to double but i couldn't find a function for `long double` which use `TCHAR`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using MSVC, `long double` is exactly the same as `double`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Format` method of `CString` class:

```
CString sNum;
long double fNum = 10.0;
sNum.Format(_T("%f"), fNum);
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll most likely find that for targets that are relevant to Microsoft Foundation Classes, `long double` and `double` are the same size.

Therefore you can build your own function stub, (which calls `_ttof`) with a static assertion `sizeof(double) == sizeof(long double)` just to be on the safe side:

`static_assert(sizeof(double) == sizeof(long double), "double and long double are not the same size");`